# Let $f'\ge0, f''\ge0 \ \forall x \in \mathbf{R}$. If there is $c$ such that $f'(c)>0$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, convergence-divergence

> Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function. Suppose $f'(x)\ge0, f''(x)\ge0 \ \forall x \in \mathbf{R}$. If there exists $c \ \in R$ such that $f'(c)>0$, show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$. My attempt is to prove the statement by absurd. So, I would like to have a feedback on my proof, please. Setting myself that $f(c_x)>0$ in my proof seems to me a little bit strange..

Suppose by absurd that $f$ converges to $L$: $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$. As $f''\ge0$, then $f$ is convex and we can deduce that $f'$ is increasing.

Consider the interval $[x,x+a]$ with $a>0$.  As $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbf{R}$, it is differentiable on $[x,x+a]$ and so continuous on $[x,x+a]$. By mean value theorem there exists $c_x\in ]x,x+a[$  such that: $f'(c_x)=\frac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}$. As $x$ is "arbitrary" in the interval, we can suppose that $f'(c_x)=\frac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}>0$. But,

$f'(c_x)=\frac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a} \iff \underbrace{\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(c_x)}_{(*)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}=\frac{L-L}{a}=0\ngtr 0$. So we got a contradiction. Thus, $f$ diverges.

**(*)** As $f'$ is increasing, as $x$ goest to infinity the inequality might hold and so $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(c_x)>0$ might hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your proof is fine, but the idea behind the proof is somewhat obscured. To me, it seems the key point is to prove there is a line of positive slope that bounds $f$ from below. Indeed, if $f'(c) > 0$, then $f(x) - f(c) = f'(c_x)(x-c) \geq f'(c)(x-c)$. The right side clearly tends to $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$, hence so must $f$.

Edit, I should also point out that this proof also works for convex $f$ (not assumed to be twice differentiable), as convex implies $f$ is above any tangent line, which is all we really used.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I didn't think about the slope, but I like the idea! When I was thinking about the proof I tried as well to pass by convex function inequality but I didn't succeed.

Comment: Could I conclude the proof without involving the limit of $f$? I mean, as I know that $f'(c_x)>0$, then its limit to infinity is $>0$ too. So it implies that $f$ diverges (By the following proposition: If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=l>0$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$)

Comment: Indeed, without even assuming $f'' \geq 0$, if you know that $\liminf_{x \to \infty} f'(x) > 0$, then $f'(x) \geq \delta > 0$ for all $x$ large enough for some $\delta>0$. Integrating then gives $f(x)-f(x_0) \geq \delta(x-x_0) \to \infty$ where $x_0$ is chosen so $f' \geq \delta$ for all $x \geq x_0$.

Comment: Alright, thank you. So, is my proof correct? Sorry for asking one more time, I just want to be sure that it holds x)

Comment: You do need to justify why $\lim f$ and $\lim f'$ exist, i.e. why $f$ or $f'$ does not oscillate, not having a limit, in order for your proof to go through. This is of course because they are both increasing functions, which always have (possibly infinite) limits. I would also be more clear about why $\lim f'(c_x) > 0$. The answer of course is again that $f'$ is increasing and has some point where $f'>0$. Then the proof would be correct, though it does feel as though you got to the solution by pushing symbols around rather than using the picture.

Comment: Why should I prove that $\lim f$ exist? The statement ask to prove that it doesn't exist, so I passed by absurd. And the fact that $\lim f'>0$ I justified it in my proof as well...

Comment: You must prove that $\lim f$ exists (but is possibly infinite) because the first step of your proof you assume for contradiction that $\lim f = L$. So if you derive a contradiction all you have shown is that $\lim f \neq L$ for any finite $L$. But this does not imply that $\lim f = \infty$, e.g. $f(x) = \sin(x)$. You must show that $\lim f$ exists, so that your proof shows $\lim f = \infty$.

Comment: Finally I see what you meant! Thank you very much. I computed some examples and understood why the hypothesis that $f$ increasing is needed in the proof.